# PHP - BB Code - Security

Tags: php

I'm very new to things like this, I'm trying to learn how to create a simple BB code type script with preg_replace, the only problem is I know it can be injected with something a simple as this.

```
[img] " onerror="javascript code"[/img]
```

So my question is, how can I ensure this is not possible, without using a BB code parser as I really don't want to use one of them. Perhaps preg_replace is not the way to go?

### Codes:

```
"/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/is",
```

is converted to

```
'<a href="\\1"><img href="\\1" src="\\1" class="lightbox_trigger"></a>',
```

Comment: why don't you want to use a parser? What's wrong with using the write tool for the job.

Comment: Because it clutters my application, it needs to be lightweight. Besides, I don't want everything they offer, I just want a few simple codes, not the full suite.

Comment: I've wrote and edited a BB code parser in the past. Yet, I fail to see how your code can be "injected with something a simple as this". Make sure to strip or encode all HTML tags before you do the matching and then apply your regex, also you may want to validate whether the content inside the bbcode tag is a valid URL.

Comment: A parser would be the best tool for the job, and if it's well written it won't be big or slow or a clutter. If you try to do it yourself it'll grow and grow as you find out just how complex the task is, you'll just end up with a badly-written parser that's bigger, slower and more of a clutter than the ones you're rejecting. If you want to do it yourself, that's fine; it's a good learning experience; but don't kid yourself that you'll write something smaller and neater than the ones out there already. You won't; not the first time you try anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? Try to use already made class/functions to do that job. That approach usually reduces the risk of security breaches.

For example [this one](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6651-PHP-Parse-BBCode-and-convert-it-into-HTML.html).

Comment: Because I would like to learn how to secure them myself, I'll check that one out.

Comment: @Tom While it's good to learn, remember, most of these libraries have all sorts of validations that were learned the hard way. Doing it yourself is a great learning exercise but is nearly guaranteed to have vulnerabilities that may eventually be attacked.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I imagined it'd be huge and cluttered, it's actually what I wanted. Accept when I can.